# Can we create two error log files using log4j in the same project for two different features

Tags: java, spring-mvc, log4j

I have implemented log4j in my application, 1 error log and 1 audit log. But now my client is asking me to create another error and audit log for another feature, so that he can quickly identify the defects in the new feature. I am trying and reading so many blogs but hard Luck. It may be possible that I have very less knowledge about log4j. Any help will be very thankful.

Comment: Create new appenders. Assign loggers to them. Use those loggers in the features. Better yet - use markers and a filtering appender.

Comment: But how will i differentiate in my java code which appender is being used? Will markers help in anyway? Let me check about markers too.

Comment: "_Use those loggers in the features_". You either need to use only "feature" loggers to log those features or you need to use a marker to mark which log lines are part of the feature. This should be exactly the same way as you differentiate messages going to your error log and your audit log.